# Python Requests with meta refresh

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello I try to login into my Router Asus-AC52U using Python Requests to scrape information using this script:

```
import requests
login_url = 'http://192.168.172.1/login.cgi'
payload = {'loginSubmitValue':'1','admin_username':'user',"admin_password":"pw"}
data_url = 'http://192.168.172.1/Advanced_VPNClient_Content.asp'

s = requests.Session()
resp = s.post(data_url, data=payload, verify=False)

test = s.get(data_url)
print test.text
```

this is the output I get:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/Main_Login.asp?page=/cgi-bin/Advanced_VPNClient_Content.asp">
</HEAD></HTML>
```

Can someone tell my what I have to do to get the source code of the pages to scrape content of it? Or what I can try to do so?

Answer (score 0):

with your same code:

```
import requests
data_url = 'Some url'
s = requests.Session()
test = s.get(data_url)
print (test.text)
```

To scrape the page you only have to do the get on the page. If you want to scrape a page once you're logged in try a combined post/get request

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('index.asp', verify=False) #web page to scrape
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
```